# Как загрузить данные гугл таблицы в бот на питоне

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

Через этот код я хотела, чтобы данные с бота  выгружались в гугл таблицу, но выдает ошибку:

> IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory:

Я создала директор в файле и просто добавила ссылку, но выдается такая ошибка, как можно исправить?

Код:

```
import gspread # pip install gspread 

gc = gspread.service_account(filename='ваш креденшел файл.json')
sh = gc.open_by_key('Ваш sheet ID')
worksheet = sh.sheet1

transaction = ['столбец А', 'столбец Б', 'столбец В']

worksheet.append_row(transaction)
```

Answer (score 0):

Всё дело в том, что тот путь, который Вы указали в качестве аргумента `filename` в функции `gspread.service_account()`, является директорией, а не файлом. Поэтому Python не может найти файл с Вашими данными.

Поэтому Вам нужно указать ПОЛНЫЙ путь к файлу, например:

```
gc = gspread.service_account(filename='D:\\ваш_креденшел_файл.json')
```

Для того, чтобы загружать данные из бота в гугл-таблицу,  Вам нужно:

1. Создать гугл-таблицу
2. Скопировать идентификатор таблицы
3. Вставить идентификатор в код

```
import gspread

gc = gspread.service_account(filename='ваш креденшел файл.json')
sh = gc.open_by_url('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/ваш_идентификатор_таблицы/edit#gid=ваш_ID_листа')
worksheet = sh.sheet1
transaction = ['столбец А', 'столбец Б', 'столбец В']
worksheet.append_row(transaction)
```

Comment: Приношу извинения, что не задала конкретного вопроса. Как сделать ссылку на гугл таблицу директорией? Я хочу, чтобы данные из бота подгружались в гугл таблицу. Возможно, не тот код

Comment: @ШынгырааКызан обновил код